# How to translate: Some thing 'can go' for some time?

Tags: english-to-german

In the following sentence 'can go' is used to express that something will stay good for two weeks. She is saying that when she stops washing her hair for two weeks they still look good. I am puzzling how to translate it.

> My tresses can go literally 2 weeks before you’d guess they were dirty.

I was thinking about 'dauern' or 'leisten'. I know literally saying 'können gehen' is most probably not a correct translation. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Since you are Dutch: What would you say in Dutch? Maybe there is a parallel construction in German that someone might recognise.

Comment: Mee gaan. In German literally 'Mit Gehen'. But I am sure that is not correct, or perhaps only good in Platdeutsch dialect. It would then be: Meine Haare gehen noch 2 Wochen mit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible:

> Meine Frisur hält noch 2 Wochen ...

Probably as colloquial as "can go"

> Meine Haare machen es noch 2 Wochen ...

Comment: Das *noch* kommt aber in dem Beispielsatz nicht vor, da ist die Gesamtdauer gemeint. Könnte vielleicht zu Verwirrung führen. Der Beispielsatz wäre ja eher: Meine Haare halten zwei Wochen, bevor man merkt, dass sie dreckig sind. Obwohl das irgendwie komisch klingt...

Comment: Stimmt, @fifaltra

Comment: What about: Meine Haare schaffen es zwei Wochen?

Answer (score 3):

The closest literal translation to the English may be:

> Meine Locken kann man glatt 2 Wochen **durchgehen lassen**...

But you may hear the variants [given already](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9781/23) much more often in this context.

Comment: Ist "Locken glatt durchgehen lassen" sowas wie "Ein Heissgetränk kalt abservieren"? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Bemüht, so nah ans Vorbild heranzukommen wie möglich, insbes. "gehen" unterzubringen, ist möglich:

```
Meine Locken können so 2 Wochen gehen, bevor man merkt, dass sie schmutzig sind.
```

Üblicher ist aber halten/machen es, wie von Ingo vorgeschlagen, der aber ein 'noch' einschmuggeln musste. Das ist nicht nötig.

```
Meine Locken können 2 Wochen halten, bevor ...
Meine Locken können es 2 Wochen machen, bevor ...
```

Comment: Das 'noch' ist kein einziger Problem. Ich kenne das Wort es ist fast wie das Holländische 'nog'. Es hat mich nicht verwirrt.